# input or date-picker disabled box in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the Status RTI Application
      
         
            
         
      
      
         
         ---------------- OR ----------------
         
      
      
         
            
            
            
            
         
      
      
         
      
      
         Submit

Comment: if ($(this).val() != '') {
                $('#number').prop('disabled', true); this is where it is setting as `true`

Comment: this is spelled wrong `$('#calenderdate').prop('disaebled', 'disaebled');`

Comment: Add HTML code as well

Comment: add html code for better understanding

Comment: Please provide more context (HTML in this case would be nice) and explain more clearly what are you trying to achieve. At this moment it's pretty a guessing game of what you want us to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're doing other way around?

if the `input` type is empty or null that is where you want to `disable` the `datecalendar` is it?

```
$('#number').keyup(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
   alert("triggered"); //Placed this to make sure it works.
    $('#calenderdate').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#calenderdate").removeClass(".datepicker, .gj-textbox-md");
    $('#calenderdate').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
    $('#calenderdate').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#calenderdate').val('');
   }
 });
```

If the selected value is `false` i.e. `($this.(val() == '') {...}` then make the `input` value as `true`.

```
$('#calenderdate').keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
     $('#number').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
     $('#number').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```